# $I_n$ be measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $I_n$ be measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R} $ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty m(I_n)<\infty$. Let $H_n=\{x: f(x)=n \}$ where $f=\sum \mathbb{1}_{I_n}$. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty nm(H_k)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty m(I_k)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$\int f dm =\int \sum_{n} \chi_{E_n} dm = \sum_{n}\int \chi_{E_n} dm=\sum_{n} m(E_n),$$
Also, $\sum_{k} k\chi_{G_{k}}=\sum_{n}\chi_{E_n}$.